# HTTPD VirtualHost config not working properly

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, httpd

Got a new VPS, installed everything, time to setup a virtual host

```
#vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/project.conf

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project.net/wordpress"
        ServerName project.net
        ServerAlias www.project.net
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    </VirtualHost>
```

Require all granted is set in the main httpd file.

```
#systemctl restart httpd
```

project.net is accessible but displays the default httpd page

System info:

```
Linux dev 2.6.32-042stab116.2 #1 SMP Fri Jun 24 15:33:57 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux with Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server built: Oct 19 2017 20:39:16
```

Comment: did you run `#systemctl restart httpd` exactly like that? including the hash sign?

Comment: no need to. the `#` makes it a comment, so that line does exactly nothing. Run the command without `#` and apache will restart.

Comment: yes without of curse  the hash was added by Thomas

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED using

```
systemctl restart php71-php-fpm
```

Seems like if i'm using the proxy:fcgi handler the php-fpm service needs a restart too.